# Tree behavior fails on save with "Syntax error or access violation"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm having trouble saving a record using the Tree behavior. If the parent_id of the record is changed, then the save will fail.

My `CmsPost` model looks like this.

```
class CmsPost extends CmsAppModel
{
    /**
     * Alias for the model.
     */
    public $name = 'CmsPost';

    /**
     *
     * @var array The behaviors for this model.
     */
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Tree' => array(
            'left' => 'left_id',
            'right' => 'right_id'
        )
    );
}
```

The saving of the record works fine. SQL dump shows this update in the history.

> UPDATE `cgtag`.`cms_posts` SET `title` = 'something else', `key` = 'somethingelse', `desc` = '', `content` = '', `parent_id` = NULL, `status` = 'review', `image_count` = 0, `published` = '2013-02-03 17:39:00', `created` = '2013-02-03 17:42:00', `updated` = '2013-02-03 17:47:00' WHERE `cgtag`.`cms_posts`.`id` = '1'

The problem is that `afterSave` callback in the Tree behavior is failing with this error.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND' at line 1

SQL Query: UPDATE `cgtag`.`cms_posts` AS `CmsPost` SET `CmsPost`.`left_id` = `CmsPost`.`left_id` + 1 WHERE `CmsPost`.`left_id` BETWEEN AND
```

The `WHERE` condition is wrong. There is value set for `left_id`.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem.

The `left_id` and `right_id` columns of the table can't be a nullable field. Have to set the default value to `0`.

Comment: According to the docs, they should default to null: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html